Separate Data in One Column into Multiple Colums
I was unable to download data from a webpage using IMPORTHTML() using either "table" or "list", so I copied and pasted the data into Sheets instead.  Each record has 5 fields, but they are sequentially in the one column:

I'd like to "split" (or separate?) the data out into 5 columns, so it becomes:

Any suggestions on how that could be done would be appreciated!

You just need WRAPROWS() function.
=WRAPROWS(A1:A15,5)



Perfect!  Thanks mate.

@maxhugen Glad to know!
